# Storing and retrieving users shopping cart from database - Cart class - CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I haven't started the coding yet and really just want to get feedback on my ideas.

I would like to know how to store a users shopping cart contents in order to be able to retrieve them once they have returned to the website.

I'm confused with the idea of allowing users to create accounts, as I've read on this website that forcing people to create an account with you in order to put items in their shopping basket is bad practice. However, if I do give the ability to have an account, then I can create a table holding the accounts information, along with having a column for storing that users shopping cart content via the CI Cart class' function `$this->cart->contents;` (which I would then have to serialize before putting it in the table, right?).

I also wanted to know if it is possible to store the contents of a users shopping basket into a column as stated above, and then retrieve it back to display as the users shopping basket contents once they log back in.

Having an account would benefit in terms of having your shopping cart items available in different browsers, as they would be associated with the account and not your session.

But if I don't want to implement customers having accounts, do I just have to implement the Cart class, with no interaction with the database (and just setting the session variables in the config file to not expire, or expire in a year etc)? I don't understand why I would need the ci_sessions table in this case (any arguments for using it?)

Really confused because I've pondered over this for a long time, getting more confused as time goes by :(. Could someone please shed some light for me. Thanks

Comment: Too many questions to really provide a good answer but you should probably look into cookies.

Comment: @dispake I've heard cookies are limited in what they can carry and somewhat insecure?

Comment: I need to engage with somebody to figure this out !

Answer (score 0):

I think its always a good idea to get customers to create accounts because

- Its a good way to stop span.  Only allowing registered and logged in users to access the checkout stages is a lot better than just letting anyone get to it
- Its also a good way to gather information about your customers that can be used for marketing

In regards to the cart you can save sessions to a database by making sure sess_use_database is set to true in the config files

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

That way you can add the customer previous items into the cart when they log back in.

But I agree with @dispake you've asked quite a lot of questions so its hard to give you a definitive answer